# React map through string1, string2, string3

Tags: arrays, reactjs, string

How do I map through something like this? It is not an array. Those are just strings with numbers. What I have come up with is something like this but it doesn't work.

```
{[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10].map((index) => (
    <p>{item.strIngredient + index}</p>
))}
```

[image]

Comment: Use object iteration: `Object.keys(yourObject).map(...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
Object.keys(Array(20).fill()).map(index => (
  <p key={index}>
    {item[`strIngredient${index}`]}
  </p>
))
```

or

You can just make use of `Object.keys(responseObject)` and filter the other keyes.

Note: Make sure key value is unique I have used index for the sake of example.

Comment: Doesn't work with `Object.keys` but works if I replace it with `[0,1,2,3].map`. Could you have a look at it?

Comment: Can you check now